# jinja variable substitution inside blockinfile module

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm looking to use variables inside blockinfile block and so I made this playbook:

```
- name: New user
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  vars:
     nome_utente: pippo
     dominio: pluto.it
     gruppo: root
  tasks:
    - name: Add new user
      blockinfile:
       dest: /root/ansible/users.yml
       backup: yes
       block: |
       '{{ nome_utente }}'@'{{ dominio }}':
               gruppo: '{{ gruppo }}'
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found character that cannot start any token

The error appears to be in '/home/francesco/test.yml': line 16, column 27, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

       block: |
       '{{ nome_utente }}'@'{{ dominio }}':
                          ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Sorry but I cannot find in any documentation if blockinfile supports jinja templating inside block module.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indentation of the block is wrong. See [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html#examples) and fix it

```yaml
    - name: Add new user
      blockinfile:
       dest: /root/ansible/users.yml
       backup: yes
       block: |
         '{{ nome_utente }}'@'{{ dominio }}':
                 gruppo: '{{ gruppo }}'
```

---

See [Popular Editors](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/community/other_tools_and_programs.html#popular-editors) that support auto-indentation and syntax highlighting.

Comment: I could not tell the fix here in this block. what is it I am missing?

Comment: @JBone, It is the 2 spaces having shifted the last but one line to the right. Compare it to the upper line, i.e `block: |`. The line started under 'b'. The indented, fixed, line starts under 'o'.

Comment: got it. thanks for clarifying. I kept looking at the syntax/spell checks but did not see for the indentation. good find. +1